# Firebase does not report all crashes in iOS while Xcode 10 reports all of them, can somehow we track all these crashes on firebase too?

Tags: ios, xcode10, firebase-crash-reporting

I am able to see numbers of crashes inside my Xcode > Organizer > Crashes tab of my live application on App Store with version number.I have successfully installed crashlytics in my app which is working well with analytics but it does not send my crashes from my app. I have seen somewhere that Firebase is not able to report NSException class crashes. is it true? can somehow we track each and every error reported in Xcode to Firebase console?

[image: Xcode: Crashes]

[image: UIKit class]

[image: CoreFoundation class]

Answer (score 3):

I could not quickly find any documentation related to Crashlytics' support of NSExceptions, except for [this](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/test-crash.html#cause-a-test-exception). However, in general, yes, Crashlytics does capture and report uncaught NSExceptions. It is fairly easy to disturb its reporting mechanism, though. So, if you are using more than one reporting framework, or a custom NSExceptionHandler, watch out.

All that said, it does not appear that any of your crashes above are uncaught exceptions. It's hard to tell, though, as the screen shots you posted do not have enough information to be absolutely sure.

One thing to keep in mind is that there are limitations of in-process reporters, like Crashlytics. One of them is they are unable to report certain OS-level events that terminate your process. From your third screenshot above, it looks like you might be experiencing at least one of those. I'd take a closer look at the crash reports, and verify exactly what kind of event is happening. It is totally possible some (or even all) of these are not detectable by 3rd party reporting systems.

Finally, with regards to forwarding crashes from Apple's system to Firebase, your best bet I think is to contact their support people. But, my guess is it is not possible.

Quick clarification:

Perhaps I was confusing, but I make a distinction between **OS-level termination event** and **crash**. In my mind, a crash is the usual null-dereference, or other illegal operation. It is *always* attributable to a particular library-function pair, even if it might not be that function's fault.

An OS-level event is something completely different, and unique to Apple's operating system. An example is attempting to modify certain OS-owned file descriptors, or trying to execute OpenGL drawing commands while backgrounded. These both terminate your app, but not in a way that is directly because of a function's behavior. It's more the app's behavior as a whole.

Comment: I think firebase simply does not detect this OS-level events which is caused due to CoreFoundation and UIkit framework. Though, thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your deep insights. please tell me more if you find any relevant help for this. Thanks

Comment: Crashlytics absolutely can detect crashes in these libraries, and all others. There's nothing magic about CoreFoundation or UIKit. They are just dynamic libraries, and behave like all other dynamic libraries on the system, including your app's executable. I added some clarification about what I mean by OS-level events, which might have been confusing.

Comment: I just found that my pod file having pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.11'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7' version.. which is pretty old compared to latest  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.9.0'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.12.0' versions..... could this be reason ?

 I just updated though... if this can help

Comment: I highly doubt it, but updating isn't a bad idea. What you could do is post actual crash reports from Xcode, instead of just the summary screen shots. That might reveal more information.